Blazor WebAssembly: Camera switch to back camera results in a black screen
I'm developing a Blazor WebAssembly application where I need to access the device camera and switch between the front and back cameras. However, when I attempt to switch to the back camera, the video feed shows a black screen. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I have implemented a button to switch the camera, but when I click it, the back camera does not always activate correctly. Sometimes it takes multiple clicks to work, and other times it just shows a black screen.
Camera.js:
let currentStream = null;
async function openCamera(facingMode) {
    if (currentStream) {
        currentStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }
    try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: {
                facingMode: facingMode
            }
        });
        currentStream = stream;
        document.getElementById('videoFeed').srcObject = stream;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error accessing camera: ', err);
    }
}

function stopCamera() {
    if (currentStream) {
        currentStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        currentStream = null;
    }
}

async function startVideo(src) {
    try {
        const permission = await checkCameraPermission();
        if (permission === 'prompt' || permission === 'granted') {
            navigator.getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false
            }, function(localMediaStream) {
                let video = document.getElementById(src);
                video.srcObject = localMediaStream;
                video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                    video.play();
                };
            }, function(err) {
                console.error('Error accessing camera:', err);
                throw err; // Propagate the error
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Camera permission denied.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error starting video:', error);
    }
}

function getFrame(src, dest, dotnetHelper) {
    let video = document.getElementById(src);
    let canvas = document.getElementById(dest);
    // Check if the video and canvas elements exist before drawing the image 
    if (video && canvas) {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 150, 150); // Resize the image on the canvas
        let resizedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        resizedCanvas.width = 200; // Set desired width
        resizedCanvas.height = 200; // Set desired height 
      
        let ctx = resizedCanvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, resizedCanvas.width, resizedCanvas.height);

        // Convert the resized image to base64 JPEG format
        let dataUrl = resizedCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        
        // Invoke the .NET method with the resized image data
        dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('ProcessImage', dataUrl);
    } else {
        console.error('Video or canvas element not found.');
    }
}

function stopVideo(src) {
    let video = document.getElementById(src);
    // Check if the video element exists before stopping
    if (video) {
        if ('srcObject' in video) {
            let tracks = video.srcObject.getTracks();
            tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
            video.srcObject = null;
        } else {
            video.src = '';
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Video element with ID ' + src + ' not found.');
    }
}

function closeCamera() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true
        }).then(function(stream) { // Stop all tracks 
            let tracks = stream.getTracks();
            tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error closing the camera: ', error);
        });
    } else {
        console.error('getUserMedia is not supported on this browser.');
    }
}

Razorpage:
@using MudBlazor
@inject IJSRuntime JSR
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar 
<div>
    <MudDialog Style="overflow: hidden;">
        <DialogContent>
            <MudCard Class="pa-2">
                <MudCardContent>
                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"> <video id="videoFeed" width="600" height="300"></video> </div> <canvas class="d-none" id="currentFrame" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin-top: 16px;">
                        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.CameraAlt" Color="Color.Primary" Size="Size.Large" OnClick="@Save" />
                        <MudIconButton Color="Color.Primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Camera" Size="Size.Large" OnClick="@RotateCamera" StartIcon="@currentIcon" />
                        <MudIconButton Color="Color.Error" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Cancel" Size="Size.Large" OnClick="@Cancel" />
                    </div>
                </MudCardContent>
            </MudCard>
        </DialogContent>
    </MudDialog>
</div> 
@code {
    private bool isMobile = false;
    private bool isFrontCamera = true;
    private bool isCameraOpen = false;
    private string currentIcon => isCameraOpen ? (isFrontCamera ? Icons.Material.Filled.Camera : Icons.Material.Filled.CameraAlt) : Icons.Material.Filled.CameraFront;
    [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Parameter] public string ImageUri {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private DotNetObjectReference < CameraDialog > oCounter;
    private string frameUri;
    private bool nestedVisible = false;
    private bool isVideoStarted = false;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        try {
            await JSR.InvokeVoidAsync("startVideo", "videoFeed");
            isMobile = await JSR.InvokeAsync < bool > ("isMobileDevice");
            isVideoStarted = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Snackbar.Add("Camera access is denied. Please allow access to the camera.", Severity.Error);
        }
    }
    private async Task RotateCamera() {
        isFrontCamera = !isFrontCamera;
        string cameraType = isFrontCamera ? "user" : "environment";
        await JSR.InvokeVoidAsync("stopCamera");
        await JSR.InvokeVoidAsync("openCamera", cameraType);
    }
    private async Task Save() {
        if (!isVideoStarted) {
            Snackbar.Add("Camera access is denied. Please allow access to the camera.", Severity.Error);
            MudDialog.Cancel();
            return;
        }
        if (oCounter == null) oCounter = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        try {
            await JSR.InvokeAsync < string > ("getFrame", "videoFeed", "currentFrame", oCounter);
            await JSR.InvokeVoidAsync("stopVideo", "videoFeed");
            isVideoStarted = false;
            MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(frameUri));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getTracks')")) {
                Snackbar.Add("Camera access is denied. Please give camera permission in the browser settings.", Severity.Error);
                MudDialog.Cancel();
            } else {
                Snackbar.Add($ "An error occurred while capturing the image. Please try again. Error details: {ex.Message}", Severity.Error);
                MudDialog.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }
    [JSInvokable] public async Task ProcessImage(string imageString) {
        frameUri = imageString;
        StateHasChanged();
        var parameters = new DialogParameters {
            {
                "ImageUri",
                frameUri
            }
        };
        var options = new DialogOptions {
            FullWidth = true
        };
    }
    private async Task Cancel() {
        if (isVideoStarted) {
            try {
                await JSR.InvokeVoidAsync("stopVideo", "videoFeed");
                isVideoStarted = false;
                MudDialog.Cancel();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getTracks')")) {
                    MudDialog.Cancel();
                } else {
                    MudDialog.Cancel();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

What I Have Tried
I tried adding a delay between stopping the current stream and starting the new one.
I added console logs to debug the flow, but still facing issues.
Expected Behavior
The back camera should activate immediately after clicking the "Rotate Camera" button without showing a black screen.
Actual Behavior
The back camera either shows a black screen or takes multiple clicks to activate.
I'm testing this on multiple devices, and the issue persists across different browsers and devices.
Camera permissions are granted properly.
Any Help or Suggestions?
I'd appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Please copy and paste the actual code in to the question as text. Images of code make it harder for to create a working MCVE of the problem, and also for us to edit to provide you with a solution.

Please use the 'Edit' link under your question. You've added your code as an answer, which will most likely get deleted. Also, please take care to format your code properly.

Please check now

In android while using rear camera i am getting blank screen and i Iphone i am getting error
